# How to get d3 treemap cell text to wrap and not overflow other cells

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The text for the cells in my d3 treemap don't wrap and overflow the other cells.  This my [project](https://codepen.io/EOJA/pen/gNPEYQ?editors=0010)

I want the text to look like this [project](https://codepen.io/HIC/pen/bxzpRR?editors=0010).  I've looked at their code (and many others) but I can't get it to work in my project.

The problem area is:

```
svg.append('text')
.selectAll('tspan')
.data(root.leaves())
.enter()
.append('tspan')
.attr("x", (d) => d.x0 + 5)
.attr("y", (d) => d.y0 + 20)
.text( (d) => d.data.name)   //.html( (d) =>       d.data.name.replace(/\s/g, "<br>"))
.attr("font-size", "0.6em")
.attr("fill", "white");
```

I tried using .html rather than .text as in the comment.  In Safari and Chrome the text still overflowed the cells.  In Firefox only the first word of the movie name was displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have two options to display the text ina similar way to the example you provide.

The first and easisest approach is to keep your code structure and make a similar procedure to split the text as the example provided:

```js
d.data.name.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g)
```

So lets change your code a little bit:

```js
  svg.selectAll('text')
      .data(root.leaves())
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .selectAll('tspan')
      .data(d => {
          return d.data.name.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g) // split the name of movie
              .map(v => {
                  return {
                      text: v,
                      x0: d.x0,                        // keep x0 reference
                      y0: d.y0                         // keep y0 reference
                  }
              });
      })
      .enter()
      .append('tspan')
      .attr("x", (d) => d.x0 + 5)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => d.y0 + 15 + (i * 10))       // offset by index 
      .text((d) => d.text)
      .attr("font-size", "0.6em")
      .attr("fill", "white");
```

This should accomplish the desired display. We have to take into account that labels are a very difficult to position and display in way which avoids overlapping since it would require a little more computation at build time.

The second approach is to change a little the code structure and create cells, pretty much like the example provided:

```js
const cell = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(root.leaves())                                    
    .enter()
    .append('g')                                              // create a group for each cell / movie
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x0},${d.y0})`)     // let the group element handle the general positioning
    .on('mousemove', d => {
      //...
    })
    .on('mouseout', d => {
      //...
    });

cell.append('rect')                                           // append rect for each cell / movie
    .attr('id', d => d.data.id)
    .attr('class', 'tile')
    .attr('data-name', d => d.data.name)
    .attr('data-value', d => d.data.value)
    .attr('data-category', d => d.data.category)
    .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
    .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
    .attr('fill', d => color(d.data.category));

cell.append('text')                                           // append text node for each cell / movie
    .selectAll('tspan')                                       
    .data(d => d.data.name.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g))         // split the name and use that as data to create indiviual tspan elements
    .enter()
    .append('tspan')                                          // append tspan node for each element of the string which got split
    .attr('font-size', '8px')
    .attr('x', 4)
    .attr('y', (d, i) => 13 + 10 * i)                         // offset the y positioning with the index of the data
    .text(d => d);
```

[CodePen for approach 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLGpyg?editors=0010)

[CodePen for approach 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEepdZ?editors=0010)

Full code for approach 1:

```js
// !! IMPORTANT README:

// You may add additional external JS and CSS as needed to complete the project, however the current external resource MUST remain in place for the tests to work. BABEL must also be left in place. 

const w = 960;
const h = 600;
const padding = 60;
const svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
              .attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
const legendsvg = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
              .attr("width", 960).attr("height", 50);
const legendPadding = 10;

d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/freeCodeCamp/testable-projects-fcc/a80ce8f9/src/data/tree_map/movie-data.json") 
.then(function(data) {
    var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function(d){ return d.value});

    var treeMap = d3.treemap()
        .size([w, h])
        .paddingInner(1);

    treeMap(root);

    const toolTip = d3
        .select("#container")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["Action", "Drama", "Adventure", "Family", "Animation", "Comedy", "Biography"])
        .range(["#db8a00", "#75b0ff", "#13ad37", "#5d6d00", "#757582", "#d37cff", "#f96868"])

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(root.leaves())
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "tile")
        .attr("data-name", (d) => d.data.name)
        .attr("data-category", (d) => d.data.category)
        .attr("data-value", (d) => d.data.value)
        .attr('x', (d) => d.x0)
        .attr('y', (d) => d.y0)
        .attr('width', (d) => d.x1 - d.x0)
        .attr('height', (d) => d.y1 - d.y0)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", (d) => color(d.parent.data.name))
        .on("mouseover", (d, i) => {
            toolTip
              .transition()
              .duration(0)
              .style("opacity", 0.8);
            toolTip
              .attr("id", "tooltip")
              .html(function() {
              return "<span>" + "Name: " + d.data.name + "<br />" + "Category: " + d.data.category + "<br />" + "Value: " + d.data.value + "</span>";
            })
              .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 87.5 + "px") // -87.5 is half width of tooltip in css
              .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 75 + "px")
              .attr("data-value", d.data.value);
          })
           .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            toolTip
              .transition()
              .duration(0)
              .style("opacity", 0);
           });

 svg.selectAll('text')
      .data(root.leaves())
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .selectAll('tspan')
      .data(d => {
          return d.data.name.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g) // split the name of movie
              .map(v => {
                  return {
                      text: v,
                      x0: d.x0,                        // keep x0 reference
                      y0: d.y0                         // keep y0 reference
                  }
              });
      })
      .enter()
      .append('tspan')
      .attr("x", (d) => d.x0 + 5)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => d.y0 + 15 + (i * 10))       // offset by index 
      .text((d) => d.text)
      .attr("font-size", "0.6em")
      .attr("fill", "white");

console.log(root.leaves());
       /*svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(root.leaves())
        .enter()
        .append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    
          .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+20})   
          .text(function(d){ return d.data.name })
          .attr("font-size", "0.6em")
          .attr("fill", "white")*/

      legendsvg.selectAll('rect')
          .data(root.children)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'legend-item')
          .style('stroke', 'white')
          .attr('x', (d,i) => i*140 )
          .attr('width', 130)
          .attr('height', 20)
          .style('fill', d => color(d.data.name))

     legendsvg.selectAll('text')
            .data(root.children)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x', (d,i) => i*140)
            .attr('y', 40)
            .text(d => d.data.name);

      //had to change the legend below because it wouldn't pass fcc test
  /*legendsvg.append("g").classed("legend", true).classed("legend-item", true);
  const legend = d3.legendColor().shape("rect")
    .shapeWidth(90).cells(7).orient("horizontal").scale(color);
  legendsvg.select(".legend").call(legend);*/ 
});
```

Full code for approach 2:

```js
// !! IMPORTANT README:

// You may add additional external JS and CSS as needed to complete the project, however the current external resource MUST remain in place for the tests to work. BABEL must also be left in place. 

const w = 960;
const h = 600;
const padding = 60;
const svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
              .attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
const legendsvg = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
              .attr("width", 960).attr("height", 50);
const legendPadding = 10;

d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/freeCodeCamp/testable-projects-fcc/a80ce8f9/src/data/tree_map/movie-data.json") 
.then(function(data) {
    var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function(d){ return d.value});

    var treeMap = d3.treemap()
        .size([w, h])
        .paddingInner(1);

    treeMap(root);

    const toolTip = d3
        .select("#container")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["Action", "Drama", "Adventure", "Family", "Animation", "Comedy", "Biography"])
        .range(["#db8a00", "#75b0ff", "#13ad37", "#5d6d00", "#757582", "#d37cff", "#f96868"])

    const cell = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(root.leaves())
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x0},${d.y0})`)
            .on('mousemove', d => {
              toolTip.transition()
                      .duration(200)
                      .style('opacity', 0.75);
              toolTip.attr('data-value', d.data.value);
              toolTip.html(
                'Name: ' + d.data.name + '<br>' +
                'Category: ' + d.data.category + '<br>' +
                'Value: ' + d.data.value
              )
                .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY + 10}px`)
                .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX + 8}px`);
            })
            .on('mouseout', d => {
              toolTip.transition()
                      .duration(200)
                      .style('opacity', 0);
            });


      cell.append('rect')
          .attr('id', d => d.data.id)
          .attr('class', 'tile')
          .attr('data-name', d => d.data.name)
          .attr('data-value', d => d.data.value)
          .attr('data-category', d => d.data.category)
          .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
          .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
          .attr('fill', d => color(d.data.category));

      cell.append('text')
          .selectAll('tspan')
          .data(d => d.data.name.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g))
          .enter()
          .append('tspan')
          .attr('font-size', '8px')
          .attr('x', 4)
          .attr('y', (d, i) => 13 + 10*i)
          .text(d => d);



      legendsvg.selectAll('rect')
          .data(root.children)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'legend-item')
          .style('stroke', 'white')
          .attr('x', (d,i) => i*140 )
          .attr('width', 130)
          .attr('height', 20)
          .style('fill', d => color(d.data.name))

     legendsvg.selectAll('text')
            .data(root.children)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x', (d,i) => i*140)
            .attr('y', 40)
            .text(d => d.data.name);

      //had to change the legend below because it wouldn't pass fcc test
  /*legendsvg.append("g").classed("legend", true).classed("legend-item", true);
  const legend = d3.legendColor().shape("rect")
    .shapeWidth(90).cells(7).orient("horizontal").scale(color);
  legendsvg.select(".legend").call(legend);*/ 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this in both approaches.  It really helped me understand this better.  I was struggling to split and position the data in approach 1.  In approach 2 in thought the cells had something to do with the positioning, but didn't get it until you explained it.